# Restrict user from selecting minutes or seconds of DateTime using DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, data-annotations

I have an "Interviews" model where a user has to be able to schedule an interview, but interviews need to be hourly. Therefore, users should only be able to pick the hour, and minutes/seconds should default to zero. How can I achieve this using DataAnnotations? Here's the code in my interviews model:

```
    [Display(Name = "Interview Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] // Something here?
    public DateTime InterviewTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: You could use a `ReqularExpressionAttribute` to display a validation error if minutes/seconds where entered that are not `0`, but a better UI might me to use a view model with 2 properties `DateTime Date` and `TimeSpan Time` and use a datepicker to select the date and a dropdownlist to render the available hours (to display options with 9.00, 10.00 etc.) and combine the values into you data model s `DateTime` property when saving

Answer (score 3):

If it ends up not being possible to use DataAnnotations to do this, you could use a backing field and validate in the setter.

```
private DateTime _interviewTime;

[Display(Name = "Interview Time")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] // Something here?
public DateTime InterviewTime {
    get {
        return _interviewTime;
    }
    set {
        if (value.Minute != 0 || value.Second != 0 || value.Millisecond != 0) {
            //either strip minutes/seconds/milliseconds or throw exception
        }
        _interviewTime = value;
    } 
}
```